# Why is my For Loop returning just one value in EJS node js?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm building something where I need to query stuff from MongoDB and display the results in the Frontend using EJS template in node.js.

Everything goes well when querying the results. All the array values are returned when I `console.log()` them but on the frontend using EJS template,  just one value is returned.

Here is my code for Querying the result:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    user.find({}, { __v: 0, _id: 0}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err; 
        result.forEach(function(u) {
            console.log(u.imgs); 
            res.render('pages/index',{
                path: u.imgs,
                state: req.session.state
        });   
    }); 
});
```

My code in EJS:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<path.length; i++) { %>        
    <%= path[i] %> 
<% } %>
```

This is the code in the `user`

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema ({


imgs: String

})
```

What do you think is wrong with my code?

Comment: Why are you looping through `res.render()` calls? This will render `n` number of pages instantaneously one after the other where `n` is the length of the `results` array, so in that perspective, you wouldn't really want to keep making render calls as your view in the browser would effectively keep refreshing moment after moment. Also, can you show us the `User` schema definition and what your end goal is with the front-end, are you trying to display the image paths per user?

Comment: No am not trying to display the image paths per user. I've provided the code in the `user` schema. @chridam

Comment: What is your expected output then?

Comment: There are two 2 values in the array but only one (the first one ) is showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the forEach loop in your query and map the results array on the path attribute i.e.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    user.find({}, { __v: 0, _id: 0}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err; 
        res.render('pages/index',{
            path: result.map(u => u.imgs),
            state: req.session.state
        });  
    }); 
});
```

Comment: This is a life saver. It is now working properly. Thanks @chridam

Answer (score 0):

You need HTML tags like

```
<ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<path.length; i++) {%>
   <li><%= path[i] %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```